# Symbol sum is generated bad

Tags: symbols, characters

i want generate equals to next image

[image]

but the sum is generate bad

```
\begin{equation}
     \label{eq:aqui-le-mostramos-como-hacerle-la-llave-grande}
     f(x) = \left\{
           \begin{array}{ll}
              1  & \mathrm{si\ }  \sum_{i=1}^{n} W\textsubscript{i}*X\textsubscript{i}+ W\textsubscript{0} \geq 0 \\
              0  & \mathrm{si\ }  \sum_{i=1}^{n} W\textsubscript{i}*X\textsubscript{i}+ W\textsubscript{k,0} < 0 \\
           \end{array}
         \right.
   \end{equation}
```

the result is

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that you want the index ranges to be displayed below and above the summation symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}                                                                                                                                                                       

\usepackage{mathtools}                                                                                                                                                                        

\begin{document}                                                                                                                                                                              

\begin{equation}                                                                                                                                                                              
\label{eq:aqui-le-mostramos-como-hacerle-la-llave-grande}                                                                                                                                     
 f(x) =                                                                                                                                                                                       
    \begin{cases}                                                                                                                                                                             
       1  & \displaystyle\mathrm{si\ }  \sum_{i=1}^{n} W_i * X_i + W_0 \geq 0 \\                                                                                                              
       0  & \displaystyle\mathrm{si\ }  \sum_{i=1}^{n} W_i * X_i + W_{k,0} < 0 \\                                                                                                               
    \end{cases}                                                                                                                                                                               
\end{equation}                                                                                                                                                                                

\end{document}
```

[image]

It is not clear why you are using `textsubscript`.

Comment: OP's using `\textsubscript` to make the subscript look like text. To make the MWE compile you can define `\newcommand{\textsubscript}[1]{_{\text{#1}}}`. The output looks different.

Comment: I get that :-) But, the index in `mathit` and the subscript in `text` looks odd. Hence my observation.

Comment: Ooh, indeed :) I overlooked that

Answer (score 11):

with the package `mathtools` you can use `dcases` environment.

```
\documentclass[spanish]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:aqui-le-mostramos-como-hacerle-la-llave-grande}
 f(x) =
    \begin{dcases}
       1  & \text{si } \sum_{i=1}^{n} W_i * X_i + W_0     \geq 0 \\
       0  & \text{si }\sum_{i=1}^{n} W_i * X_i + W_{k,0} <    0
    \end{dcases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Note: variables in indices is usually written in italic shape.

[image]

**edit:**
considered [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) comment. now "si" is consider that means "if" (and not math operator as i did in the first answer version).

Comment: “Si” is most likely “if” (the OP is from Spain).

Comment: @egreg, this make sense. i'm not familiar with Spanish language.  corrected.

Comment: @Zarko Is theree difference between `dcases` and `cases`?

Comment: @minhthien_2016, yes, it is: `dcase` put its contents in `\displaystyle` mode (`d` in `dcases` indicate `display`) meanwhile `cases` not. it is defined in the package `mathtools` (which is an extension of `\amsmath`).

Comment: @Zarko Thank you for explain. I have just tried.

Answer (score 2):

use `\limits` as shown below

```
\begin{array}{ll}
              1  &   \mathrm{si\ } \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} W\textsubscript{i}*X\textsubscript{i}+ W\textsubscript{0} \geq 0 \\ \\
              0  & \mathrm{si\ }  \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} W\textsubscript{i}*X\textsubscript{i}+ W\textsubscript{k,0} < 0 \\
\end{array}
```

[image: sumsym]

Comment: Note that when you use `\limits`, you don't change the glyph for \sum (it stays in textstyle), which can sometime be useful (although in that case, I find the sum too small).